# how can save current state of activity and reload that in any time

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, android-activity

have 4 activity with names : main , p1 , p2 ,p3
want if user was in p1 or p2 or p3 when come out with exit button and relaunch app again in main activity with resume button can go to the same activity was .
there is my code : main activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_page);


        Button button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);



      button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,p1.class);
              startActivity(intent);
          }
      });
    }
}
```

xml :

```
 <Button
        android:text="resume"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:text="next"
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

activity p1:

```
public class p1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.p1);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btne);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(p1.this,p2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        Button button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btne2);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(p1.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        }
    }
```

xml:

```
 <Button
        android:text="next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btne"/>

    <Button
        android:text="go in main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btne2"/>
```

and p2,p3 like p1 . please help if any one can

Comment: You need to rephrase the question. Even if anyone wants to help he cannot because no one can understand what you intend to do

Comment: When you start new Activity, it is added to stack, so when user click back button or when you call `finish();` he will go back to previous activity.

Comment: Pictorial representation of what you want if possible would be great and can be easily understood

Comment: for example : if i was in p2 and click go to main . then when click resume in main go in p2

Comment: Can you please tell the exact purpose of What you are trying to do? I guess using fragments can help you better. But still i would like to know the purpose of this flow.

Comment: @MohammedAtif want if i was in activity p2 then click in go to main . when i am in main then click resume . i go into activity p2 . like games have ply and resume ... –

Comment: Please use fragments in this case, it might help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If your main activity starts all the rest then you only need to call `finish();` to finish them, and your main activity will be back on top. So instead of writing for example in p1:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(p1.this,MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

write:

```
p1.this.finish();
```

If on the other hand you want to close all the activities opened until your main activity (ie. you have MainActivity -> p1 -> p2, and you want only MainActivity to be left, p1 and p2 finished) then use this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: for example : if i was in p2 and click go to main . then when click resume in main go in p2

Comment: want if i was in activity p2 then click in go to main . when i am in main then click resume . i go into activity p2 . like games have ply and resume ...

Comment: @erfan, so you want to only hide p2 - and not close it? If that is true, then when user presses PLAY button close Main before opening p2, then when user presses PAUSE - open Main using startActivity. When user presses RESUME in Main call finish() in Main - in this case your PLAY button would have to change to RESUME. There are other aproaches, you could have two Main activities opened, the very first one would show PLAY button, the version for resuming gameplay would  show RESUME button.

Answer (score 0):

In your MainActivity, declare a global variable resumeIntent:

```
public static Intent resumeIntent = null;
```

When you click the Resume button (in MainActivity) it should go to the previous activity, implement the click event as follows:

```
        if (resumeIntent != null) {
            startActivity(resumeIntent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Intent to resume !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

In those activities P1, P2 and P3, the code for Go To Main button is like below:

```
btnGoToMain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MainActivity.resumeIntent = getIntent();
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Hope it helps !